# Show that $\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+} \int^1_0 ax^{a−1}f(x)dx=f(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ and continuous at 0. Show that $$\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+} \int^1_0 ax^{a−1}f(x)dx=f(0).$$

Can anyone share some insight on this one? I have no idea where to begin. Maybe a substitution?

Comment: What is $t$? Is it $a$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: You can split the integral in two and make an estimate for both parts. I fact, the integral for the power part goes to $1$ as $a$ goes to $0$ no matter what upper limit we take.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^1 ax^{a-1}f(0)\mathrm{d}x = f(0) x^a\Bigg|_0^1=f(0)$ and use this to show that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $$\Bigg| \int_0^1 ax^{a-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x - f(0)\Bigg| < \epsilon$$ See the details in my answer

Answer (score 2):

> Our goal is to prove that $\forall \epsilon >0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $$0<a<\delta \implies \bigg| \int_0^1 ax^{a-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x-f(0)\bigg|<\epsilon$$

First of all, note that for $a>0$ we have

$$\int_0^1 ax^{a-1}f(0)\mathrm{d}x = f(0) x^a\Bigg|_0^1=f(0)$$

Therefore, for any $a>0$, monotonicity of integration and the above identity tells us that
$$\Bigg| \int_0^1 ax^{a-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x - f(0)\Bigg|=\Bigg| \int_0^1 ax^{a-1}\bigg(f(x)-f(0)\bigg)\mathrm{d}x\Bigg| \leqslant  \int_0^1 ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x \,\,\,\,\, (\star)$$

This immediately suggests that we can use the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$: indeed for $\epsilon/2$, there exists $0<\gamma < 1$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)| < \epsilon/2$.

Since $f \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$, we immediately conclude that $f-f(0) \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$ and $\big|f-f(0)\big| \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$. Also, since the product of integrable functions is integrable, $x^{a-1}\big|f-f(0)\big| \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$ for any $a>0$.

Now let's split the integral in $(\star)$ at $x=\gamma$. We have

$$\int_0^1 ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x=\underbrace{\int_0^{\gamma} ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x}_\color{red}{{\text{ continuity of $f$ at $x=0$}}} + \underbrace{\int_{\gamma}^{1} ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x}_\color{red}{{\text{ integrability of $\large x^{a-1}|f-f(0)|$}}}$$

Therefore, we can control both terms for the reasons explained under each term, we have

$$\int_0^1 ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x \leqslant  \frac{\epsilon}{2}\cdot x^a\Bigg|_0^{\gamma} +  aM = \frac{\epsilon}{2}\gamma^a +  aM < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+aM\,\,\,\,\,(\star\star)$$

where $\int_{\gamma}^{1} x^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x=M$ is a non-negative real number because $x^{a-1}\big|f-f(0)\big| \in \mathcal{R}[0,1]$ and the last inequality holds because $0 < \gamma <1$. The case $M=0$ is already done. (why?). Hence, assuming $M>0$ and combining $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$, we get

$$\Bigg| \int_0^1 ax^{a-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x - f(0)\Bigg|\leqslant\int_0^1 ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+aM$$

So, we just need to take $\delta$ such that $\frac{\epsilon}{2}+aM < \epsilon$. Just take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2M+1}$. $\fbox{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: How did you "control" the first term when you split up the integral? You said because $f$ is continuous at 0?

Comment: @user439126  because of the monotonicity of integration and continuity of $f$ at $0$, $\big|f(x)-f(0)\big| < \epsilon/2$ implies that $$\int_0^{\gamma} ax^{a-1}\bigg|f(x)-f(0)\bigg|\mathrm{d}x < \int_0^{\gamma} ax^{a-1} \big(\epsilon/2\big) \mathrm{d}x = \epsilon/2 \int_0^{\gamma} ax^{a-1} \mathrm{d}x = \epsilon/2 \cdot {\gamma}^{a}$$

Comment: @user439126 If you're asking why $|f(x)-f(0)|< \epsilon/2$, read the paragraph that starts with "This immediately suggests that we can use the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$..."

Answer (score 0):

We may assume $f(0)=0$. 
Then let $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $r >0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ when $x \leq r$.

Then, for any $1>a>0$, $\left|\int{ax^{a-1}f(x)}\right| \leq \int_{0}^r{|f(x)|ax^{a-1}}+\int_r^1{ax^{a-1}|f(x)|} \leq \epsilon r^a +ar^{a-1}\int_0^1{|f|}$.

I am quite convinced you can finish now.

Comment: I don't see how you got the very last term on the right side of you inequality. @Mindlack

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed here. I suppose that once I figure out how that last term came from,  that taking the limit as $a \to 0^+$ gives us the answer we want, but how would one justify passing the limit into the integral?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+} \int^1_0 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx=f(0)\iff\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int^1_0 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx-f(0)\right)=0$$

$$\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int^1_0 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx-f(0)\right)=$$

$$=\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int_0^a ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx-f(0)+\int_a^1 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx\right)=$$

$$=\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left( \int_0^a ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx-f(0)\right)+\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int_a^1 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx\right)=$$

$$=\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left( \int_0^a ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx-a^af(0)\right)+\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int_a^1 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx\right)=\tag 1$$

$$=\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left( \int_0^a ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx-\int_0^a ax^{a−1}f(0)\mathbb dx\right)+\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int_a^1 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx\right)=\tag 2$$

$$=\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int_0^a ax^{a−1}(f(x)-f(0))\mathbb dx\right)+\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\int_a^1 ax^{a−1}f(x)\mathbb dx\right)\leq$$

$$\leq\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\sup\limits_{y\in[0,a]}\{f(y)-f(0)\}\int_0^a ax^{a−1}\mathbb dx\right)+\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\sup\limits_{y\in[0,1]}\{f(y)\}\int_a^1 ax^{a−1}\mathbb dx\right)=$$

$$=\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\sup\limits_{y\in[0,a]}\{f(y)-f(0)\}[x^a]_0^a\right)+\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\left(\sup\limits_{y\in[0,1]}\{f(y)\}[x^a]_a^1\right)=$$

$$\require{cancel}=\left(\cancelto{0}{\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}\sup\limits_{y\in[0,a]}\{f(y)-f(0)\}}\cancelto{1}{\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}a^a}\right)+\left(\sup\limits_{y\in[0,1]}\{f(y)\}\cancelto{0}{\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}(1-a^a)}\right)=0$$

$(1)$ as $\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+}a^af(0)=f(0)$

$(2)$ $a^a=\int_0^aax^{a-1}$